# Question concerning File Handling

Tags: iphone, xcode, file

i got the following problem :
i am trying to create a file with the following Code :

```
NSString *homeDirectory = NSHomeDirectory();
NSString *documentDirectory = [homeDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
NSString *filePath = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Test.txt"];

NSFileHandle *savedFile = nil;
savedFile = [[NSFileHandle FileHandleForWritingAtPath:filePath]retain];

NSString *data = @"testmessage";
[savedFile writeData:[string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[savedFile synchronizeFile];
[savedFile closeFile];
```

My Question is  the following. Running this on a MAC does not give me any Errors whatsoever. But the File itself seems to be nonexistant or at least not locateable.
I need to find and access the File and i have to be able to export it to my Mac using a mobile iOS Device

thanks in advance :)

h4wkeye

Comment: What do you get if you add `NSLog(@"%@", filePath);` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check that savedFile is not nil (see [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileHandle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000304-SW19) here).

```
NSString *homeDirectory = NSHomeDirectory();
NSString *documentDirectory = [homeDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
NSString *filePath = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Test.txt"];

NSFileHandle *savedFile = nil;
savedFile = [[NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:filePath]retain];

if (nil == savedFile) {
    NSLog(@"Could not create saved file at %@", filePath);
}

NSString *data = @"testmessage";
[savedFile writeData:[string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[savedFile synchronizeFile];
[savedFile closeFile];
```